# Getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while creating directory using os.mkdir

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

```
import os

os.mkdir(r'C:\Users\Puneeth.Prabhu\Documents\Hello')

File "C:/Users/Puneeth.Prabhu/.spyder-py3/testingpage.py", line 3, in <module>
os.mkdir(r'C:\Users\Puneeth.Prabhu\Documents\Hello')
```

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I'm running the above code to create a directory using python. But ending up with str object is not callable error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: pls share full code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing all you code are you? You have most likely re-assigned os.mkdir to a string somewhere before calling it. An example:

```
 os.mkdir = 'Some text'
 os.mkdir('/random/thing')
```

This will give your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
full_path = os.path.join(["C", "Users", "Puneeth.Prabhu", "Documents", "Hello"])
os.mkdir(full_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to remove the `r` from the `os.mkdir()` function call.
The code would look like:

```
import os
os.mkdir('/YOUR/DESIGNATED/DIRECTORY_NAME')
```

Python raw string is created by prefixing a string literal with ‘r’ or ‘R’. Python raw string treats backslash () as a literal character. This is useful when we want to have a string that contains backslash and don’t want it to be treated as an escape character.

Source: [Python Raw String](https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use "r" in the argument.
Try this:

```
os.mkdir('C:\Users\Puneeth.Prabhu\Documents\Hello')
```